# Why am I getting an overflow error during an array assignment?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that sets some global arrays. The program was  working fine until a couple hours ago. It's been run a few times today already. I haven't changed anything but the size of the array (from 99500 - 99900, 9), is this the problem? If it is the size of the array, is there a way to store this much data with a different data structure (collection, dict, user-defined)?

```
    Const PartMaterialsFilePath = "C:\Users\jayferreira\Desktop\"
    Const PartMaterialsFileName = "Part Materials.xlsm"

    Function getPPNWorksheet() As Worksheet
        If isWkbkOpen(PartMaterialsFileName) Then
            Set getPPNWorksheet = Workbooks(PartMaterialsFileName).Worksheets(2)
        Else
            Set getPPNWorksheet = Workbooks.Open(PartMaterialsFilePath + PartMaterialsFileName).Worksheets(2)
        End If
    End Function

    Global partDescriptions() As String
    Global partRevisions() As String * 5
    Global partRevisionDates() As String * 10
    Global partWeights() As Single
    Global partNumbers() As String * 6
    Global PartMaterials As Dictionary
    Global initialized As Boolean
    Function setGlobals()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Load loadingBar
        loadingBar.Show
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim dataArr() As Variant
        Dim mGPPN As Worksheet
        Dim multipleOf As Long
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim i As Long
        loadingBar.Text.Caption = "Loading ppn.xlsx..."
        Set mGPPN = MCGBookFunctions.getPPNWorksheet
        lastRow = MCGBookFunctions.getLastRow(mGPPN, , 1, 1)
        loadingBar.Text.Caption = "Loading Data..."
        mGPPN.Activate
        dataArr = mGPPN.Range("A2", "I" & lastRow) ''this is where the overflow error occurs
        MCGBookFunctions.closePartMaterialsworkbook True ''closes mGPPN
        Set mGPPN = Nothing
        ReDim partDescriptions(lastRow)
        ReDim partRevisions(lastRow)
        ReDim partRevisionDates(lastRow)
        ReDim partWeights(lastRow)
        ReDim partNumbers(lastRow)
        multipleOf = lastRow / 100
        For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
            partNumbers(i) = dataArr(i, 1)
            partDescriptions(i) = dataArr(i, 2)
            partRevisions(i) = dataArr(i, 3)
            partRevisionDates(i) = dataArr(i, 4)
            partWeights(i) = dataArr(i, 5) * 1000 
            If i Mod multipleOf = 0 Then
                counter = counter + 1
                loadingBar.Caption = "Storing Data..."
                loadingBar.Text.Caption = counter & "% Completed"
                loadingBar.Bar.Width = counter * 2
                DoEvents
            End If
        Next
        loadingBar.Caption = "Getting part materials from database..."
        Set PartMaterials = DataBase.GetMaterials()
        initialized = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Unload loadingBar
    End Function
```

note: the line that kicks the error is two lines before the arrays are redimmed. 'dataArr = mGPPN.Range("A2", "I" & lastRow)' as is commented in the code.

note: I played around with the range size, and can assign Range("A2", "I7804") to the array, but not a row more. I have assigned a much larger range to the array multiple times today, up until a couple of hours ago.

Comment: Do you know the value of `lastRow` on that line when the code breaks?

Comment: @MattCremeens lastRow = 99241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `.Value2` in `mGPPN.Range("A2", "I" & lastRow).Value2` solved my problem. I assume it has something to do with the way the cells are formatted, producing an overflow when trying to store something like a Date as a string, perhaps?